# Ansible docker invalid character %

Tags: sql, docker, ansible, vagrant

I am writing some ansible to automate my docker deployments.
I am trying to set an env variable to be % but I get this error:

```
    ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found character that cannot start any token

The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/roles/zoneminder_docker/tasks/main.yml': line 21, column 24, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:

          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlpsswd
          MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: %
                           ^ here
```

Is there any way to escape this character? As if I exclude this line, my deployment fails.

Comment: Try to force the hostname the system will run on

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to escape this character? As if I exclude this line, my deployment fails.

The thing you are looking for is to make that value a string literal:

```
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlpsswd
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
```